# Forbid authenticated users from visiting login page in nuxt js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I have the following code snipped from my `middleware/auth.js` that redirects users to login page if the users are unauthenticated.

```js
export default function ({ store, redirect }) {
  if (!store.state.admin.isAdmin) {
    redirect('/auth/login')
  }
}
```

Now I want to forbid authenticated users visiting login page and redirect to ('/manage/dashboard') when they hit the login url.

I have used the following approach in my login view:

```js
  mounted () {
    if (localStorage.getItem('token') && localStorage.getItem('userId')) {
      this.$router.replace({ path: '/admin/dashboard' })
    }
  }
```

This works but the execution is too slow and user can see login page for few seconds.

What is the efficient way to achieve the redirect ?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't access localStorage from the login view, I would prefer to set it in your store and then access the store. I have not run this code but I think you want to do something like this.

You can create another check-auth.js middleware and add that to your login view.

check-auth.js

```
export default function (context) {
    context.store.dispatch('initAuth', context.req);
}
```

store/index.js

```
state:{
     authenticated:false;
}
mutations: {
    setAuthentication(state, auth) {
            state.authenticated = auth;
        },
}
actions: {
    initAuth(vuexContext, req) {
        if (localStorage.getItem('token') && localStorage.getItem('userId')){
            vuexContext.commit('setAuthentication', true);
        }else{
            vuexContext.commit('setAuthentication', false);
        }
    }
},
getters: {
        isAuthenticated(state) {
            return state.authenticated;
        },
    },
```

Then check if the user is authenticated
auth.js

```
if (!context.store.getters.isAuthenticated) {
    context.redirect('/auth/login');
}
```

add middleware to your view

```
export default {
    middleware: ['check-auth', 'auth'],
    components: {},
    methods: {},
};
```

Comment: This code fails with error message localStorage is not defined. This is happening because of the lifecycle hook of Nuxt js. Middleware is running before the DOM is initialized.

Comment: If you have not set your localStorage in your code then you need to set it before you try to use it in inintAuth. I have not set the localStorage in the code above, for example add localStorage.setItem('token', token); into your function where you get your token before you try to use it.

Comment: So where you authenticate your user your should set you localStorage.